# How to compare text values in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table as shown below. I would like to compare column A "Text" values with the next text value in the same column. In case they are equal to put an index i=1 if they are different, to put the next index i+1.
The problem is that in the I get right index for each column B cell except cells that remain blank (as on the picture). Can anyone help with it, please?

[image]

```
Sub Ma1()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i, n As Integer

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
LastRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Column1 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3:A" & LastRow)

n = 1
For i = 3 To LastRow
On Error Resume Next
If Range("A" & i) = Range("A" & i + 1) Then
Range("B" & i) = n
Else: n = n + 1
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify your IF:

```
If Range("A" & i) = Range("A" & i + 1) Then
   Range("B" & i) = n
Else
   n = n + 1
   Range("B" & i) = n-1
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Sub Ma1()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i, n As Integer

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
LastRow = Sheets(1).Range("A" & Sheets(1).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Column1 = Sheets(1).Range("A3:A" & LastRow)

n = 1
For i = 3 To LastRow
    On Error Resume Next
    If Range("A" & i) = Range("A" & i + 1) Then
        Range("B" & i) = n
    ElseIf Range("A" & i) <> Range("A" & i + 1) And _
           Range("A" & i) = Range("A" & i - 1) Then
        Range("B" & i) = n
        n = n + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```